# write an Rdata file from C++

Tags: c++, r

Suppose I have a C++ program that has a vector of objects that I want to write out to an Rdata data.frame file, one observation per element of the vector. How can I do that? Here is an example. Suppose I have

```
vector<Student> myStudents;
```

And `Student` is a class which has two data members, `name` which is of type `std::string` and `grade` which is of type `int`.

Is my only option to write a csv file?

Note that Rdata is a binary format so I guess I would need to use a library.

A search for Rdata [r] [C++] came up empty.

Comment: Can you provide a brief example of the required file format?

Comment: @mathematician1975 sure but it is a binary format (updating post to mention this). Would an example still help?

Comment: I think you are much better off using R API and write a C++ extension on a long run. See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html

Comment: @VladLazarenko thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping there was another way, but I guess not. I use C++ to input the files, which I could call from R, but that just doesn't feel like the most natural approach.

Comment: Not a regular R user, but check http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code.html Maybe something from here can help.

Comment: @Ivarpoiss thanks. rcpp is great. However, it's run within R. I still would like to write an Rdata file outside of `R`. For example, I would like my code to be usable without having `R` installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think nobody has bothered to extract a binary file writer from the R sources to be used independently from R.

Almost twenty years ago I did the same for Octave files as their format is simply: two integers for 'n' and 'k', followed by 'n * k' of data -- so you could read / write with two function calls each.

I fear that for R you would have to cover too many of R's headers -- so the easiest (?) route may be to give the data to R, maybe via Rserve ('loose' connection over tcp/ip) and RInside (tighter connection via embedding), and have R write it.

*Edit:* In the years since the original answer was written, one such library has been created: [librdata](https://github.com/WizardMac/librdata).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a function that saves a list in a RData. This example is based on the previous answer :

```
void save_List_RData(const List &list_Data, const CharacterVector &file_Name)
{
  Environment base("package:base");
  Environment env = new_env();
  env["list_Data"] = list_Data;
  Function save = base["save"];
  CharacterVector all(1);
  all[0] = "list_Data";
  save(Named("list", all), Named("envir", env), Named("file", file_Name));
  Rcout << "File " << file_Name << " has been saved! \\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fit everyone needs (of those who is googling this question), but this way you can save individual or multiple variables:

```cpp
using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using Eigen::Map; 
using Eigen::MatrixXi;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

Environment base("package:base");

Function save = base["save"];
Function saveRDS = base["saveRDS"];

MatrixXd M = MatrixXd::Identity(3,3);

NumericMatrix xx(wrap(M));
NumericMatrix xx1(wrap(M));
NumericMatrix xx2(wrap(M));

base["xx"] = xx;
base["xx1"] = xx1;
base["xx2"] = xx2;

vector<string> lst;
lst.push_back("xx");
lst.push_back("xx1");
lst.push_back("xx2");
CharacterVector all = wrap(lst);

save(Named("list", all), Named("envir", base) , Named("file","Identities.RData"));
saveRDS(xx,Named("file","Identity.RDs"));
return wrap(M);
```

```r
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppEigen)

src <- '
#put here cpp code shown above 
'

saveworkspace <- cxxfunction(signature(), src, plugin = "RcppEigen")
saveworkspace()
list.files(pattern="*.RD*")


[1] "Identity.RDs"
[2] "Identities.RData"
```

I'm not 100% sure if this C++ code will work in standalone library/executable.

**NB**: Initially I missed the comment that the solution should be independent of `R`, but for those who is searching for exactly the same question, but they are ok with dependency on `R`, this could be helpful.